# Prove that if $g$ is integrable $f$ is integrable

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Let $\|x\|= \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p \biggr)^{\!1/p\;}$ for a given $p>1$  and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$ of the form $f(x)=g(\|x\|)$ for a given $g:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$

> Prove that if $g$ is integrable then $f$ is integrable and
> $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f =nV_1\int_0^\infty g(r)r^{n-1} \, dr$ where $V_a$ is the
> volume of $B_a=\{x;\|x\|\leq a\}$.

My work:

So I started by taking $g$ to be $\mathbb{1}_{[0,a]}$ for some $a>0$. In this case $f=\mathbb{1}_{B_a}$ and if $g$ is integrable then $f$ is too, then I took $g$ to be a step function which is a linear combination of indicator functions so again if $g$ is integrable so is $f$.

Now because every integrable function is sandwiched between two step functions with integrals that differ by $\epsilon$ we conclude that if $g$ is integrable $f$ is as well. (Not too sure about this part)

Now to prove the integral equality above, I checked it on $n=2$ and $p=2$ and it was true but I am pretty lost on how to do an induction here..Any ideas?

Comment: Because $g\in L([0,\infty))$ is true that $g$ can be aprrox with a step function (and because g is positive, you can suppose that are incressing). Now, the equality follows inmediatlly if you use fubbini's theorem (fixing the first n-1 variables)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite see how fubini's theorem solves it..Would you mind developing it?

Comment: A similar question that deals with a spherical-type coordinates is done here [The law induced by a norm $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to Lebesgue's measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740846/the-law-induced-by-a-norm-rho-on-mathbbrn-with-respect-to-lebesgues-me)