# How are the following integrals equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Several textbooks I've read make the claim that for any $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$$ \frac{1}{k!}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^k f(x) dx =\int_{[0,\infty)^{k+1}} f(x_1+x_2+\dots + x_{k+1}) \ dx_1 \dots dx_{k+1}  $$

where we assume both sides of the equality are finite (e.g $f$ is continuous and compactly supported). I would preferably like to start with the left hand side (LHS) and obtain the right hand side (RHS) because the LHS is the "natural" integral to look at in the context of these textbooks.

However, given that this equality is true, it seems easier to start with the right hand side. (If you have a motivated proof that starts with the LHS and gets to the RHS I would love to see that).

Starting with the RHS, we can substitute $ x = x_1 + \dots x_k + x_{k+1}$ and have $dx = dx_k $. Therefore,

$$\int_{[0,\infty)^{k+1}} f(x_1+x_2+\dots + x_{k+1}) \ dx_1 \dots dx_{k+1} = \int_{[0,\infty)^k} \int_{x_1+\dots + x_k}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx   \ dx_1 \dots dx_k$$

We are integrating over the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \text{and}\  x_i \in \mathbb{R}| 0 \leq x_i \leq \infty \ \text{and} \ (x_1 + \dots + x_k) \leq x \leq \infty \} $

I was thinking of changing the order of integration because that worked in the case $k=1$, but I'm running into trouble with doing that for general $k$. Any ideas?

Comment: You are on the right track. In  the case $k=1$ you can complete  the argument by  simply changing the order of integration. The general case follows by repeatedly changing order of integration.

Comment: In last integral function is independent from $x_1,..,x_k$ so you can take it out from their integration.

Comment: @zkutch I don't think that observation helps me.

Comment: The formula is wrong, according to both my numerics and my own analysis. You need to divide by $k!$

Comment: @FShrike Oh yes, you are correct! This could help me interpolate my work into an answer. In particular it's the integral on the left that should be divided by $k!$.

Comment: My [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3871314) with another idea (and slightly more general result).

Comment: @metamorphy That's actually wild. This means the truncated power comes up in all sorts of integrals of the form $\int_{R^k} f( g(x_1, \dots x_k))$ for some $g$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$This is a very pretty result, thank you for sharing it.

Theorem:

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a measurable function that is integrable over $[0,\infty)$ and for which the below $n$-dimensional integral exists, for $n\in\Bbb N$. Then: $$\int_{[0,\infty)^n}f(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)\d x_1\d x_2\cdots\d x_n=\color{red}{\frac{1}{(n-1)!}}\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}f(x)\d x$$

Notes: we don’t need compactly supported and smooth (a.k.a “bump”). However, every such function will satisfy the above hypotheses.

Proof:

By induction. Clearly the case $n=1$ is correct. Now take $n>1$ and inductively assume the result for $n\mapsto n-1$. Furthermore, the function will satisfy the Fubini theorem hypotheses, so we can break the integrals down however we wish. From your own work: $$J:=\int_{[0,\infty)^n}f(x_1+\cdots+x_n)=\int_{[0,\infty)^{n-1}}\int_{x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}}^\infty f(x)\d x\d x_1\cdots\d x_{n-1}$$

Define $F:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ by $F(x)=\int_x^\infty f(y)\d y$. We have: $$J=\int_{[0,\infty)^{n-1}}F(x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1})\d x_1\cdots\d x_{n-1}$$And $F$ satisfies the hypotheses for the case $(n-1)$. By induction and Fubini: $$J=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}\int_0^\infty x^{n-2}F(x)\d x=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}\int_0^\infty x^{n-2}\int_x^\infty f(y)\d y\d x$$Being careful with the regions of integration, we interchange: $$J=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}\int_0^\infty f(y)\int_0^y x^{n-2}\d x\d y=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty y^{n-1}f(y)\d y$$As desired!

Comment: Beautiful. Very simple proof.

Comment: Also sorry for editing a few times and thereby making some of your remarks in this answer appear unrelated. I was trying to make the question simpler to read so that someone could actually give a full answer.

Comment: You called the result beautiful, so if you're interested, the context of this question actually comes from the study of splines (piece-wise polynomial functions). If you take the truncated power function $\frac{x_+^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{k!}\text{max}(0, x^k) $ then you can view it as the distribution given on $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R} )$ given by the RHS above.   Why would you complicate such a simple looking function by viewing it as a distribution? Well it turns out viewing it as a distribution makes generalizing the truncated power to a multivariate piecewise polynomial much more natural.

Comment: @Dan1618 Thank you for explaining some of the context. So, it seems as if the action of this distribution on any suitable test function would be to map: $$f\mapsto\int_{[0,\infty)^{n+1}}f(x_1+\cdots+x_{n+1})\,\mathrm{d}x_1\cdots\,\mathrm{d}x_{n+1}$$Which is multivariate in form. I can, kind of, see how this could be relevant for splines. Nice!

Comment: I don't see how your formula differs from their (supposedly incorrect) formula. You've replaced $k+1$ with $n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, you’ve arrived a little late Sir, they have since edited the post! I should probably delete my old comments. Previously, they had forgotten the $1/n!$ term.

Answer (score 2):

The answer I upvoted helped me come up with an answer in the direction I wanted which also clarifies the need for a factorial mentioned in the comments. I post the answer below which is also done by induction.

The base case $k =0$ is clear. Suppose the result is true up to $k-1$.

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^kf(x)}{k!} \ dx   & = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) \bigg(\int_0^{x} \frac{x_1^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \ dx_1 \bigg) \ dx     \\ 
& = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{x} \frac{x_1^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} f(x) \ dx_1 \ dx  \\
\text{(By changing the order of integration)} & = \int_0^{\infty} \int_{x_1}^{\infty} \frac{x_1^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} f(x) \ dx \  dx_1 \\ 
& = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x_1^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \int_{x_1}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx \ dx_1 \\ 
\text{(By simply shifting $x$ by $x_1$)} & = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x_1^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \int_0^{\infty} f(x +x_1) \ dx \ dx_1 \\ 
& = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x_1^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} F(x_1)\ dx_1  
\end{align}

where $F(x_1) = \displaystyle{\int_0^{\infty} f(x+x_1) \ dx }$. By induction, this last integral is given by

\begin{align} \int_{[0,\infty)^k} F(x_2 + x_2 + \dots x_{k+1})  \ dx_2 \dots \ dx_{k+1} & = \int_{[0,\infty)^{k+1}} f(x+x_2+ \dots x_{k+1})  \ dx\  dx_2 \dots \ dx_{k+1}\\
\text{Relabeling variables} \ & = \int_{[0,\infty)^{k+1}} f(x_1+ \dots x_k+x_{k+1})  \ dx_1 \dots \ dx_{k+1}\end{align}

Comment: This is also nice +1